# Disable :active pseudo selector for some buttons

Tags: css, html

I need to disable `:active` pseudo selector for some (but not all) buttons. So button stays with exact same styles as it was as user fires `onmousedown` event.

I've tried to duplicate css styles from default `btn` to `btn:active` and it partially works, but some styles got overwritten.

Maybe there is some other options. I'm fine with using some quick and dirty solution for now.

In case someone need the code - posting it below:

```
.btn-system {
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 21px;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  border-radius: 4.5px;
  border-top-color: rgb(198, 198, 198);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-left-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  border-right-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}

.btn-system.btn-active:not([disabled]), .btn-system:active {
  /*color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  border-top-color: rgb(64, 150, 248);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(9, 85, 255);
  border-left-color: rgb(39, 122, 252);
  border-right-color: rgb(39, 122, 252);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(94, 168, 249), rgb(14, 117, 255));*/
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0px 17px 1px 16px;
  border-top-color: rgb(64, 150, 248);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(9, 85, 255);
  border-left-color: rgb(39, 122, 252);
  border-right-color: rgb(39, 122, 252);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(94, 168, 249), rgb(14, 117, 255));
}
.btn-system:active {
  border-top-color: rgb(30, 114, 254);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(3, 56, 216);
  border-left-color: rgb(16, 82, 233);
  border-right-color: rgb(17, 82, 227);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(64, 140, 253), rgb(11, 93, 224));
}
```

Comment: `I've tried to duplicate css styles from default btn to btn:active and it partially works, but some styles got overwritten.` ... we need more information, what get's overwritten. A screenshot or jsfiddle of the expected/actual result would be usefull.

Comment: @ad_on_is so there is no other solution except duplicating style?

Answer (score 0):

Give id's to those buttons with which you want to use pseudo selector

Hope this helps